# Can't load friends images with facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, image

I'am following a tutorial from Facebook for making a mobile website application.
But i can't load the images from friends.
I get this:

```
<img src="[object Object]">
```

It should work, because i copied the entire code from the example (only changed appId)

Here is the full code:

```
    <html>
<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Hello world" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Hello World" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Hello World!  This is my mobile web sample app." />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hackbook/img/facebook_icon_large.png"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
          e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
          document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
          }());
  </script>

  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({ appId: '226909127331855', 
      status: true, 
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true});

      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);  
    };
  </script>

  <script>
   function handleStatusChange(response) {
     document.body.className = response.authResponse ? 'connected' : 'not_connected';

     if (response.authResponse) {
       console.log(response);
       updateUserInfo(response);
     }
   }
   </script>

   <div id="login">
     <p><button onClick="loginUser();">Login</button></p>
   </div>
   <div id="logout">
     <div id="user-info"></div>
     <p><button  onClick="FB.logout();">Logout</button></p>
   </div>

  <script>
    function loginUser() {    
      FB.login(function(response) { }, {scope:'email'});    
    }
  </script>

  <style>
    body.connected #login { display: none; }
    body.connected #logout { display: block; }
    body.not_connected #login { display: block; }
    body.not_connected #logout { display: none; }
  </style>

  <div id="user-info"></div>
  <script>
    function updateUserInfo(response) {
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        document.getElementById('user-info').innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture">' + response.name;
      });
    }
  </script>

  <a href="#" onclick="getUserFriends();">Get friends</a><br>
  <div id="user-friends"></div>
  <script>
  function getUserFriends() {
    FB.api('/me/friends&fields=name,picture', function(response) {
      console.log('Got friends: ', response);

      if (!response.error) {
        var markup = '';

        var friends = response.data;

        for (var i=0; i < friends.length && i < 25; i++) {
          var friend = friends[i];

          markup += '<img src="' + friend.picture + '"> ' + friend.name + '<br>';
        }

        document.getElementById('user-friends').innerHTML = markup;
      }
    });
  }
  </script>

  <a href="#" onclick="publishStory();">Publish feed story</a><br>
  <script>
  function publishStory() {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      name: 'I\'m building a social mobile web app!',
      caption: 'This web app is going to be awesome.',
      description: 'Check out Facebook\'s developer site to start building.',
      link: 'http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hello',
      picture: 'http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hackbook/img/facebook_icon_large.png'
    }, 
    function(response) {
      console.log('publishStory response: ', response);
    });
    return false;
  }
  </script>

  <a href="#" onclick="sendRequest();">Send request</a><br>
  <script>
  function sendRequest() {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'invites you to learn how to make your mobile web app social',
    }, 
    function(response) {
      console.log('sendRequest response: ', response);
    });
  }
  </script>

  <fb:like></fb:like>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/web/build/

Comment: +1 for giving me chance to see fb developer console again after long time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing only a bit wrong 
go for this link [face book developer tool for graph api for freindlist link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends&fields=name,picture)

you will get friends something like

```
{
      "name": "Nishant Porwal", 
      "id": "522901714", 
      "picture": {
        "data": {
          "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/372008_522901714_1470071180_q.jpg", 
          "is_silhouette": false
        }
      }
    }
```

and now see your code

```
 '<img src="' + friend.picture + '"> '
```

you have to parse 
you defently find that you are placing an object instead of placing url so change your code and get url because src always work for image url :) might  i am given you an idea where you are wrong

change it to

```
'<img src="' + friend.picture.data.url + '"> '
```

Comment: let me know if you are having any more confusion

Comment: Thanks for your help. If i follow your link then i get only a "name" and "id". like so: `{
      "name": "Bella Ekkie",
      "id": "1398062267"
    }` And no 'picture' . I think thats the problem, but how do i fix this?

Comment: type "me/friends&fields=name,picture" in next area of get dropdown and you will get your friend list i think you are new with graph api ?

Comment: Yes i am. Its the beginners tutorial ;) I get the picture url now with the link you gave me.

Comment: now you got where you are wrong just do one thing change your frnd image tag to  '<img src="' + friend.picture.data.url + '"> ' and you will get the result

Comment: Yes thank you! sorry for the late reaction. Was away for a few days. People like you make this site so great.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your code to this:

```
'<img src="' + friend.picture.data.url + '"> '
```

As @Gyan mentioned, take a look at the open graph explorer to see what the underlying data structure looks like.

Answer (score 0):

General advice is to check the object type returned by your method. Since you are being returned an object, there is likely a property like image you can reference from that object... something like objectName.imageURI